Error creating bean with name 'secutiryConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation
I got this error while doing Spring Secutiry, please help me, my code
Error creating bean with name 'secutiryConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference or an asynchronous initialization dependency?
package ecourse.secutiry;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecutiryConfig {
    @Bean 
    public UserDetailsService getUserDetailsServices(){
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider getDaoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(getUserDetailsServices());
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(getDaoAuthenticationProvider());
}

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("admin") // Chỉ người dùng có quyền "admin" mới được truy cập các URL bắt đầu bằng "/admin/"
            .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("user") // Chỉ người dùng có quyền "user" mới được truy cập các URL bắt đầu bằng "/user/"
            .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll() // Cho phép tất cả mọi người truy cập các URL còn lại
        )
        .formLogin((form) -> form
            .loginPage("/home/signin") // Định nghĩa trang đăng nhập tùy chỉnh tại URL "/home/signin"
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login") // URL xử lý đăng nhập
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/") // URL chuyển hướng sau khi đăng nhập thành công
        )
        .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable()); // Vô hiệu hóa CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery)
        return http.build();
    }
}


I tried ask ChatGPT but no hope
Im using spring boot 3.4.0

Ditch the configureGlobal and getDaoAuthenticationProvider methods. You don't need them.
